# Using Local variable value's in Jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, global, local, var

i'v got this functions at my script:

```
(document).ready(function () {
$(".plcardFirst").change(function() {
valueFirst = $( ".plcardFirst" ).val();
        });
$(".plcardSecond").change(function() {
valueSecond = $( ".plcardSecond" ).val();
    });
});
```

How can i use `valueFirst` and `valueSecond` values to calculate and run an if statement? 
many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that **javascript** have **function scope** and **not block scope** which means variables declared inside a function with the keyword **var** can be used **inside that function only**.
But here you are declaring **valueFirst** and **valueSecond** without the **keyword var**, so they are both considered as a **global variables so you can access them anytime you want and anywhere even inside an if statement**

You can also use this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var valueFirst,valueSecond; // declaring both variables at the beginning after document.ready

$(".plcardFirst").change(function() {
valueFirst = $( ".plcardFirst" ).val();
        });
$(".plcardSecond").change(function() {
valueSecond = $( ".plcardSecond" ).val();
    });

// now you can use valueFirst and valueSecond of course if $( ".plcardFirst" ).val() and $( ".plcardSecond" ).val(); return something

//example if(valueFirst == valueSecond){alert('both values are equal ');}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
 var valueFirst =0,valueSecond =0;
 (document).ready(function () {
       $(".plcardFirst").change(function() {
            valueFirst = $( ".plcardFirst" ).val();
       });
       $(".plcardSecond").change(function() {
           valueSecond = $( ".plcardSecond" ).val();
       });
 });
```